# Restart needed to connect to public WiFi network Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I've never been able to figure out why I could never connect to public WiFi networks using Kubuntu 18.04 (it also happened on 17.04). That is, until I figured out a restart does allow me to connect afterwards.

I found the following: https://askubuntu.com/questions/904299/why-do-i-have-to-reboot-to-be-connect-to-the-wifi, on which they recommend restarting the network manager. This does not help. Neither does flushing the DNS cache.

This is driving me mad because otherwise it's almost never necessary to restart. Any ideas?

Comment: [ubuntu.se] would be a much more suitable place to ask. This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I've got slightly different issue recently related to missing Network in Ubuntu. You can try this:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Ref: https://itcodehub.blogspot.com/2019/03/ubuntu-network-not-showing-or-connecting.html